# DumpFile has wrong name after export in Oracle 11g XE?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, datapump

I have a problem when export database to dump file in oracle 11g xe.
It's run success but my dump file have wrong file name when i used japanese.
**This is my command to export dump file:**
`EXPDP test/123 TABLES=t_tprt_kki_kmk_mpg_mstr DIRECTORY=BACKUP_DIR DUMPFILE=テンプレート公開項目マッピングマスタ.dmp LOGFILE=テンプレート公開項目マッピングマスタ.log`

And my file retrived: `ウンシレーエ公開項目マィゴングマスタ.DMP`. I think that may be due to uppercase. I used `nls_lang` to set language and charset.
Please help me solved it.

Comment: What is the database character set; and what are your operating system language settings? What did you actually have NLS_LANG set to? (You can edit the question to add that information)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve it. There are a couple of bugs on MOS (e.g. 22004180, 22004268 - though for 12c) which refer to garbled dumpfile names when multibyte characters are used (both examples happen to refer to Japenese but it's probably more general than that), which have been closed as not-a-bug. Which seems odd as that isn't listed as a restriction [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL841).

The only 'workaround' seems to be to not use multibyte characters in the file name, which doesn't really help you.

You could export with a singlebyte-character-only name and then rename the file at operating system level; which is a bit of a pain, and you may find a similar issue on import unless you rename it back to singlebyte characters for that too.